# PostgreSQL psycopg2 error: there is no unique constraint / InvalidForeignKey

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, psycopg2

I have the following models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

class EventList(models.Model):
    event_contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, through=EventMembership)

class EventMembership(models.Model):
    event_list = models.ForeignKey(EventList, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    event_contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

However, when applying migrations for `EventMembership` on a completely clean database I get the following error:

> psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint
>   matching given keys for referenced table "contacts_contact"

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('lists', '0001_initial'),
        ('contacts', '0002_auto_20200308_2253'),
    ]

    operations = [
       migrations.CreateModel(
            name='EventMembership',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('event_contact', apps.utils.django_multitenant.fields.TenantForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='contacts.Contact')),
                ('event_list', apps.utils.django_multitenant.fields.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='lists.EventList'))
                  ]
                ]
```

Table `contacts_contact` clearly has a unique constraint in `id` as the primary key.

What could be causing this error? / How do I debug this?

Comment: it seems like ```EventMembership``` must have unique constraint on the fields event_list and event_contact. Which discards null=True in both fields of course.

Comment: @AndreyNelubin Yes it does, but (added as a meta unique constraint) but how would this throw the error? If I remove this constraint the error still exists?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do it step by step. Now you are trying to create a foreign key relationship with a table that is not in the database yet. So comment everything out except for Contact model, apply migrations, then add EventList etc. If you are relying on the fact that Contact model goes first, well, it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see how this approach of commenting out everything works. Please could you explain further? E.g. 1) What is causing this error?, 2) how do I fix it?

Comment: Re: dependencies, this should already be addressed in the migration file, which you can see already has Contact model loading first

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. You actually can create a model and a relationship to this model in a single migration. I was pretty sure I'd failed to do that before. I just tried it and it worked fine. What surprises me is that you didn't get an error `'EventMembership' is not defined`, since it should be in quotes: `through='EventMembership'`. Are you sure your db is clean? Because if you created e.g. Contact table, then used `drop table` on it, there would still be many dependencies left.

Comment: Do you have all these models in one models.py file? There is a quote from the docs that may be related to your problem: "Apps without migrations must not have relations (ForeignKey, ManyToManyField, etc.) to apps with migrations. Sometimes it may work, but it’s not supported."

Comment: No, they are separate apps (it's not possible to change this). I think what's happening is there is a constraint requirement created in the first model that is applied in a `0002_auto` migration, and the dependency of the second model points to `0001_initial`. I am not sure how to correct this though.